# wrong query inserting value in specific row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute the following query where I want to add a value in the column firstime in the corresponding row with $netid and mac.

```
$query="INSERT INTO node WHERE netid='".$netid."' AND mac='" . $_GET['mac'] . "' (firstime) VALUES ('" . $firstcheck . "')";
mysql_query($query, $conn) or die("Error executing query: ".mysql_error($conn));
```

when I try I get the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE netid='28' AND mac='24:A4:3C:40:4D:EB' (firstime) VALUES ('2014-01-16 12:0' at line 1

Any Idea??

Comment: You should know that this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want an `update`:

```
update node
    set firsttime = '" . $firstcheck . "'
    WHERE netid = '".$netid."' AND mac = '" . $_GET['mac'] . "';
```

`insert` inserts a new row into the table, not a new value into the row.

`update` updates a value in a row.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `WHERE` clause for `INSERT` query since it makes no sense

Here is a documentation page about its proper syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

A scientific guess: what you need is [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

The **WHERE** conditions must go at after the colums and values declaration.

```
INSERT INTO node  (firstime) VALUES ('" . $firstcheck . "') WHERE netid='".$netid."'    
AND mac='" . $_GET['mac'] . "'";
```

Also use **prepared statements** and sanitize user submitted data,  in order to prevent a **SQL INJECTION** which is a present and clear threaten.

Comment: And what `WHERE` in `INSERT` means?

Comment: Yes indeed,  it must be UPDATED instead of INSERTED.

Comment: I got it,  it`s totally impossible to INSERT based on a WHERE condition due to the fact that there is a new record to be created, so there is by no means a WHERE condition.  May I offer apologies.

Comment: This is also ok. SQL injection is also good topic, but do you have any link to suggest me where I can make more investigation about that?